# Catch output from "nginx -t" with php

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to make a simple control panel for my webserver running nginx with php-fpm.

I've managed to catch result of `service php5-fpm restart` and `service nginx reload`, but the output from `nginx -t` apparently doesn't work the same way?

I've tried with `$out = shell_exec('nginx -t');`, like I use for the other 2 examples above. But when I run the script, it just prints out the result and the variable `$out` is null.

I've also tried with both `shell()` using the output argument and `popen()` combined with `fread()`, but that's the same outcome.

What I want to achieve is updating a field in my mysql database with the result of `nginx -t`.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What do you get when you enter `nginx -t` from a terminal? Also, please upload the full scope of your PHP code.

Comment: This is solely programming question and belongs to stack overflow. `nginx -t` probably prints output to stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a programming than ubuntu question so it should probably be in stack overflow.

However your problem is probably errors not being caught because you are asking for STDOUT and errors are being output to STDERR.

There are two possible solutions.

The first is to use a php function to capture STDERR. I don't know enough php to answer that.

The second is to direct STDERR into STDOUT. Run

```
nginx -t 2>&1
```

This tells the shell to move everything written to STDERR to STDOUT instead.

For more info on file streams and stderr in particular: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29

Comment: Thanks, that did it!
Sorry if I've used a wrong forum, I thought it was as much an Ubuntu-matter. And as it turned out, it was the command which need to be changed ;-)